# Return a count in a function - Mysql

Tags: mysql, function

I have a complex SQL and wish to have a function that I can call that returns the number of rows.

I have written:

```
BEGIN
    declare thetotal INT;
    select count(id) AS thetotal from countries where id = countryid;
    RETURN thetotal;
END;
```

but it will not let me return from the select.

Comment: replace "AS" with "INTO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SELECT..INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) instead:

```
BEGIN
    declare thetotal INT;
    select count(id) INTO thetotal from countries where id = countryid;
    RETURN thetotal;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
declare thetotal INT;
select @thetotal =count(id)  from countries where id = countryid;
RETURN thetotal;
END;
```

Comment: Don't use session-scope vars inside stored code if you can avoid them. Because you'll set your session var globally. This is a side-effect which may cause unpredictable result in case if your var later will be re-used somewhere in your queries. Also, `select @thetotal =count(id)` has no sense, it's __comparison__ and not __assignment__